# final model in cross-validation using caret package

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I did cross validation on my data using Random Forest method in Caret package, R says that the final model is built using mtry=34, does it mean that in the final Random Forest (resulted from cross-validation) only 34 variables of the parameters in my data set were used for splitting in trees?

```
> output
Random Forest 

 375 samples
  592 predictors
  2 classes: 'alzheimer', 'control' 

  No pre-processing
  Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
  Summary of sample sizes: 250, 250, 250 
  Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
  2   0.6826667  0.3565541
  34   0.7600000  0.5194246
  591   0.7173333  0.4343563

   Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
   The final value used for the model was mtry = 34.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've built your random forest using the `caret` package, a tip is to use the `$finalModel` to obtain the summary of your final model, which is the model that is selected using a pre-defined parameter (default: OOB Accuracy).

Now to answer your question:

From the image below, you can see the random forest randomly chooses from 34 (my example is 31, but you get the point) variables on each split. This is **not** to be confused with using only 34 variables to grow each tree, as per your question. In fact, all variables are used in a sufficiently large random forest; Only, on each node, one variable is picked from a pool of 34 to reduce variance of the model. This makes each tree more independent from each another and consequently, the gains from averaging over a large number of trees more significant.

[image]

The tree-growing process for each tree is as follow (**bold** for emphasis, and assuming you're using the `randomForest` implementation from `caret` or from `randomForest` directly):

- For a dataset with N x M dimension (N for observations, M for number of variables), sample (~two-third) of N with replacement from the original data and use this new sample as training set with the observations left out (~one-third) used as a test set
- A number `m` (smaller than `M`) is **specified such that at each node split, `m` variables are selected at random out of the `M` and the best candidate out of `m` (measured by information gain) is used to split the node**. `m` is a constant during the forest growing
- Each tree is grown to the largest extent possible without pre- or post-pruning

Sorry for the 2 month late answer, but I thought this is a great question and a shame if it doesn't get a more elaborated explanation about what the `mtry` parameter truly does. It's quite often misunderstood so I thought I would add an answer here!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of randomForest:

> mtry: Number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each
>   split.

In this case the final model considers 34 random variables per split in the tree.